# My query works only in the right order of streams in Siddhi CEP engine

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I want to produce a stream from 4 input streams. For example,

```
from s1[at1>0], s2[at2==2], s3[at3>1], s4[at4 is null]
select 'k' as res
insert into s5;
```

The first problem is that, if I input events in other order in Siddhi try it, it doesn't produce the result. 
Second, if I don't input one of the events, again doesn't produce the result. And, if I don't put value in attribute `at4`, it produces an error.
My goal is to put `'k'` in res if `at4` doesn't have value or event `s4` doesn't come.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by  - if I input events in other order in Siddhi try it ,it doesn't produce the result

Comment: i mean, events will come in mixed order, for example s2 before s1, and in that case it wont work. i think i solved that with joins, but its more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In above you are using a sequence[1]. Sequence demands all incoming events to come in particular order. So in the above given query you will only get an output if and only if you get events in following exact order one after another.
1. Event where at1>0
2. Event where at2=2
3. Event where at3>1
4. Event where at4 = null

If one of the events does not come or the condition does not mach you won't get an output. That's why you don't get any results and that is expected behavior. Can you confirm whether your requierment is only to " put 'k' in res if at4 doesn't have value or event s4 doesn't come."  If that is the case I can help you regarding the query.

Siddhi try it does not allow you to keep the attribute filed undefined. That's why you get and error when you does not put value. Also Siddhi does not allow you to not sent an attribute which is already defined. Siddhi always mandate you to send all defined attributes. Only possibility is that attribute getting null which is covered by your check.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Sequence

Comment: i want to put 'k' in res if s4 doesn't come yes